# Is there a "yield" like construct in R?

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I'm kinda new to  R and just started using it to plot some graphs.

I have this code:

```
times=integer(nrow(df));
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  time=df[i+1,4]-df[i,4];
  times[i]<-time
}
```

There must be a more clever way to do this, without first initializing times, isn't it?
I'm not sure, but what I'm searching for is something like:

```
times <- for(i in 1:nrow(df)) yield df[i+1,4]-df[i,4]
```

(I know this is not valid code :))
I hope this question isn't asked already. I searched and didn't find anything concrete on "yield" and initializing of arrays.

As requested....

Sample data in df:

```
7926 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7927 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7928 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7929 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7930 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7931 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7932 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7933 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7934 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7935 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7936 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7937 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
7938 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER START 1.319242e+12
7939 08:00:27:ed:f3:e5 MESSAGEHANDLER   END 1.319242e+12
```

After my loop is times is:

```
[7921] 508 500 497 501 466 502 505 500 488 501 500 501 490 501 478 501 501 501
[7939]  NA
```

Ok, to get more concrete, what I really want to do is this:

```
times1=integer(nrow(df));for(i in 1:nrow(df)) { if (df[i,3] == "START") times1[i]<-df[i+1,4]-df[i,4]}
times2=integer(nrow(df));for(i in 1:nrow(df)) { if (df[i,3] == "END") times2[i]<-df[i+1,4]-df[i,4]}
```

Then the output is something like for times1:

```
[7921]   0 500   0 501   0 502   0 500   0 501   0 501   0 501   0 501   0 501
[7939]   0
```

But I need:

```
[3960]   500   501   502   500   501   501   501   501   501
```

In words:

I'm parsing measured data from a csv file, which lands in df as seeing above.
This is for "START" followed by "END"

The data in df describes that a packet was received when there is a "START" in df[,3] at a specific unixtime in miliseconds in df[,4].
Now I need to calculate the time that passed from receiving to sending (this is the time, my machine needs to analyze the RECEIVED PACKET and calculate a result to SEND it.)
So END in df[,3] means packet was sent successfully at unixtime df[,4].

The other case is "END" followed by "START"

This is the time that passed in between "my packet was sent" and a new one "was received".

I add now a sample of a csv and my full code for reproduction:

```
#load csv in df!
df = read.csv("/tmp/measure.csv",FALSE)
absolute=integer(nrow(df));for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {time=df[i,4]-df[1,4];absolute[i]<-(time/1000)}
times=integer(nrow(df));for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {time=df[i+1,4]-df[i,4];times[i]<-time}
#plot(absolute,times)
plot(absolute,times,lty=1,pch=1,col="#11223399",type="l")
lines(absolute,array(mean(times,na.rm=1),nrow(df)),col="red")
```

Here my measure.csv:

```
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238175202
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238175690
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238176195
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238176665
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238177167
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238177669
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238178172
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238178639
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238179139
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238179658
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238180161
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238180654
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238181154
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238181669
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238182170
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,START,1319238182629
08:00:27:ed:f3:e5,TMCMESSAGEHANDLER,END,1319238183130
```

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: You will make it much easier to understand what you want if you post sample data and expected results.

Comment: it is not about the result, they are just fine. Its all about what can the language. But I post some of my data. So my code works, but it looks awkward.

Comment: @Andrie: I cannot use diff, because I need to do further checks kind of if (df[i,3] == START && df[i+1,3] == END) do this else do that

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea at all what you are trying to do.  You seem to be doing some operation on a vector.  Maybe it will help if you 1) describe in words what this operation is supposed to be doing, and 2) make your example minimally reproducible.

Comment: added all my stuff I'm currently using to plot my data. The check what type i want to calculate is missing, because it does not work yet. (Zeros in times)

Comment: One caution: do messages arrive in sequential order?  If packets overlap, you'll need to split by the packet ID.

Comment: First of all you should drop your Python practices which are orthogonal to how R should be used -- read about vectorization and functional features, for instance in [R-intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope I'm not too far off- why not avoid the loop altogether?:

```
    # generate some data sort of similar to yours:
    DF <- data.frame(pos4 = rep(c("START","END"),10),times=rep(0,20))
    DF$times[DF$pos4=="START"] <- 1:10
    DF$times[DF$pos4=="END"] <- DF$times[DF$pos4=="START"]+runif(10)
    DF
    DF
        pos4 times
    1  START  1.000000
    2    END  1.750459
    3  START  2.000000
    4    END  2.212599
    5  START  3.000000
    6    END  3.974809
    ....
```

I'm assuming the the START and END times in your dataset are in order..

```
    (times <- DF$times[DF$pos4=="END"] - DF$times[DF$pos4=="START"]) 
    [1] 0.7504590 0.2125986 0.9748094 0.3313644 0.3448410 0.8677022 0.9534317
    [8] 0.1279304 0.6500212 0.1798664
```

not sure about what kind of checks you need to do, since they weren't in the for loop you posted in the question.

-----------------EDIT---------------------------

to include from the comment below that appears to have gotten it right,
this really was a question about indexing:
where:

```
    DIFFS <- diff(DF$times)
```

gives you all the differences, you just wanted to split this into two objects, one for even indices, another for odd indices:

```
    times1 <- DIFFS[seq(from=1,to=length(DIFFS),by=2)]
    times2 <- DIFFS[seq(from=2,to=length(DIFFS),by=2)]
```

and unrelated, but also useful: you used 'absolute' and 'df' for the names of objects in your code, but these are also functions in R, so although it works, it's better form to give them names that aren't already taken. Glad you got what you were after!

Comment: this is nearly that what I#m looking for. Im testing currently.

Comment: ok, this works fine for calculating difference from 1,2 3,4 5,6 but how do i calculate  2,3 and 4,5? i only get him to calculate 2,1 4,3 6,5 (I need the next START not the previous). Sorry is it understandable what I mean? :)

Comment: To add to this evildead, R is very different than other languages you may be used to. The use of loops is rare. Loops are much slower in R than other methods you may have available to you.

Comment: I'm confident with not using loops at all. I read R is a kinda like scheme dialect, so this makes sense. Normally in "functional capable  languages " you have something like a so called "for expression" with a yield (at least in scala and python). Why I used a real loop in the first place was because I need to address a "next" element from a relative position. Which is currently the problem with the posted expression, it takes the first one one it finds and then iterates over the collection.

Comment: um, I understood the first time that a START followed in the next line by END is a pair, and you want END-START, i.e 2-1 ?, your comment sounds like what you really want is the start in line 3 minus the END in line 2- is that the case? If so, then does the START in line 1 just need to be disregarded? Does your dataset really start off as END-START-END...? That's a quick fix if so

Comment: yeah, sorry, I just looked up at the df you posted, just switch around the expression in put above: DF$times[DF$pos4=="START"] - DF$times[DF$pos4=="END"] (i.e. the time between the end of the previous operation and the start of the next?)

Comment: no sorry that was my fault, it starts with "START" Its always START-END-START-END.........

Comment: I need to calculate both. First dataset should be END-START and second START - END (position START relative to END -1 ) so e.g. [1] START [2] END [3] START ....  I want to calculate [3] START - [2] END for the second dataset

Comment: if you want both, i.e. the lag from START to END & the lag from the END of an operation until the start of the next, then I think Andrie's answer is the best- diff() take the first difference down the entire series, producing a vector of differences (1 shorter than nrow(df))

Comment: then do diff(), like Andrie says, for your first differences (END1-START1): diff(DF$times)[seq(from=1,to=length(DF$times),by=2)], and for your second kind of differences (START2-END1): diff(DF$times)[seq(from=2,to=length(DF$times),by=2)]

Comment: nice thank you. Works perfect, the trick was appending the seq how it should count.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to calculate the difference between successive elements in a vector.  In that case you are looking for `diff`:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1:10, 5)

x
[1] 1 2 9 5 3

diff(x)
[1]  1  7 -4 -2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like

```
lapply(sequence(nrow(df)-1),function(i,df) df[i+1,4]-df[i,4],df)
```

or also try `sapply` in place of `lapply` (otherwise, same syntax).

Edit:

More specifically, I think

```
times <- sapply(sequence(nrow(df)-1),function(i,df) df[i+1,4]-df[i,4],df)
```

or

```
times <- unlist(lapply(sequence(nrow(df)-1),function(i,df) df[i+1,4]-df[i,4],df))
```

would do the trick. Regarding the reshaping, there is no identifying variable in `df` that would pair the start and end times together, so would have to do it manually assuming that the two to be paired occur in successive rows:

```
times <- apply(matrix(df[,4],ncol=2,byrow=TRUE),1,diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my way out the door but 2 comments: 1)  add column headers to the data frame  2)  I think the OP needs the reshape package to split his start end times into 2 different columns called start and then end.  then use End-Start operation on a vector .

Comment: I like tim riffe's response better than my own. It's faster.

Comment: I agree- reshaping the dataframe would make it easier